# Cannot connect to Socket via PHP

Tags: php, sockets, server

I cannot connect to socket via PHP (Insurgency Sandstorm)

I can connect to google.com and example.com on port 80 of course... but cannot connect to any socket on my Insurgency Sandstorm server...

**for example, the following super simple PHP code fails…**

(I replaced the IP and port with 2's obviously)

```
$s = fsockopen("22.22.22.22", 2222, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if (!$s) { die( "$errstr ($errno)" ); }
fclose($s);
```

**I get the following Error:**

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 22.22.22.22:2222
>   (Connection timed out) in /blah/blah/rcontest.php on line 41
>   Connection timed out (110)

Comment: Are you sure that port is open? You can check it by this in terminal: ```nc -zv google.com 80```

Comment: thanks Sergey.  I actually solved it by running this script on my localhost XAMPP practice server and it connected fine... so therefore I determined that it was a problem with my host.  And so it is exactly as you say... the port was not open.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  My host (bluehost) does not by default offer a Dedicated IP.  Therefore my hosting is a Shared IP and so the only ports that are open are 80 and mysql ports and maybe a some others.

Regardless, I was required to purchase a Dedicated IP.  Now I can direct them (bluehost) to open any port I want (in this example 2222)  Pretty pathetic... but now it works and the connection executes flawlessly.

Also... Thanks Sergey.